# Source code branching strategy for multiple clients

Tags: git, tfs, branch

We are developing an ERP solution as a product with multiple modules, Source is maintained in TFS, there are different teams for each modules, and so we are splitting the Source code to different Team projects in TFS. The main challenge we are facing now is about the source code maintenance.

We took a branch from our main-branch and named it as product-release-branch. Now we have customization for each clients, so we are taking branches from product-release-branch and naming as client1-branch and so on.

```
-- main-branch 
      -- product-branch 
            -- client1-branch
            -- client2-branch
```

Is this the approach we need to follow or do we need follow a better method?
is there any standard practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me .. If you are working on multiple modules and different teams are working then i would recommend to follow feature branch workflow. Please find the link here which explains everything . [link](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: is there any TFS specific links you can provide ?

Comment: Let me search and get back to you

Comment: After discussing with some experts, We finalised the Feature base system with release branching strategy.

Comment: Great to hear. I thik the answer suggested by me is good enough for starting. Please vote this as an accepted answer.